# Setting decimal to precision 2 places in win32 message box

Tags: winapi, c++-cli

I created my first win32 form. I have a bug, it is when a decimal is shown in the message box as output, it prints out to about the 10th decimal place. In a console program I could just use the precision(2) command to set the decimal place to 2 places, but I cant figure it out in win32. Here is the code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 0 && this->radioButton1->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (b - a) * 100;


        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }

    else if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 0 && this->radioButton2->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (a-b) * 100;


        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }

    if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 1 && this->radioButton1->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (b - a) * 50;


        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }

    else if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 1 && this->radioButton2->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (a - b) * 50;

        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }

    if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 2 && this->radioButton1->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (b - a) * 50;


        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }

    else if (this->comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 2 && this->radioButton2->Checked == true) {
        double a = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox1->Text->Trim());
        double b = Convert::ToDouble(this->textBox2->Text->Trim());

        double sum = (a - b) * 50;

        MessageBox::Show("$" + sum);
    }   


}
```

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with a message box. Can't you separate the aspects of converting values to text, and then subsequently displaying that text.

Comment: My buddy told me the same thing. I'm in a c++ class and I'm bored so I decided to try some winapi. But I will learn C# for my serious GUI applications. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific format for your string conversion, you need to tell it which format to use. The standard numeric formats are listed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

In order to convert a double to a string with two decimal places, you would use the fixed-point format.

```
sum.ToString("F2")
```

However, since you've got that dollar sign there, it seems that the values you're converting are dollars. In that case, we can do better, and have it use the proper currency format. This will use the currency symbol for your current culture, or you can specify a culture to use.

```
sum.ToString("C")
```